# Optimizing the following make file

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have the following makefile, that works fine, I just wanted to see if it is possible to further optimize such makefile:

```
CC=gcc
FLAGS=-lm -std=c99
PROJECT1_FOLDER=./Project1/
PROJECT2_FOLDER=./Project2/
PROJECT3_FOLDER=./Project3/
DEBUG1=$(PROJECT1_FOLDER)Debug/
DEBUG2=$(PROJECT2_FOLDER)Debug/
DEBUG3=$(PROJECT3_FOLDER)Debug/

all : test1 test2 test3
.PHONY : all
.PHONY : clean

test1 : $(addprefix $(PROJECT1_FOLDER), src1.c header1.h main.c)
    $(CC) $(addprefix $(PROJECT1_FOLDER), src1.c main.c) -I$(PROJECT1_FOLDER) -o $(DEBUG1)test1

test2 : $(addprefix $(PROJECT2_FOLDER), src2.c header2.h main.c)
    $(CC) $(addprefix $(PROJECT2_FOLDER), src2.c main.c) -I$(PROJECT2_FOLDER) -o $(DEBUG2)test2

test3 : $(addprefix $(PROJECT3_FOLDER), src3.c header3.h main.c)
    $(CC) $(addprefix $(PROJECT3_FOLDER), src3.c main.c) -I$(PROJECT3_FOLDER) -o $(DEBUG3)test3

clean :
    rm $(DEBUG1)test1 $(DEBUG2)test2 $(DEBUG3)test3
```

I can see the recipes test1, test2 and test3 are basically the same, is there a way to collapse them in a single line?

Comment: Why are you outputting to a separate `Debug` directory? Do you ultimately intend to have debug and non-debug versions? Why aren't you using separate compilation?

Comment: "I have the following makefile..." Is this *really* it? If not post the
real one, so we can see in what ways the recipes are actually similar.

Comment: @user657267, Just because I wanted to learn how to use a makefile to compilate different projects, each project has it's own debug stuff etc, it's just a sample makefile nothing professional.

Comment: @MikeKinghan, it's the real one.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your test1 2 and 3 together than use something like this at the end your rule:

```
cp your_binary folder
```

Also next time, try to compile using .o files instead of .c during your compilation by using this rule :

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o) ## SRCS are your .c files
```

Comment: What do you mean by combining test1,2 and 3 together?